# RegEx: Get id out of an url

Tags: regex

i would like to get the id out of this url/string:

http://domain.com/product/sale/1029487807-4a3p9/

This must be something like this:

```
/(sale\/(\d{10}\-[a-z0-9]))/s
```

Any idea how to get the id? Thanks!

Comment: Is it for PHP? You could parse it with `parse_url`.

Comment: Your matching after the dash says only matching a single character and not a sequence of characters

Comment: How about: /sale\/(\d{10}\-[a-z0-9]+)/s

Answer (score 2):

You can use anchor `$` to specify the end of string then use a negated character class to get the id within the first capture group:

```
\/([^/]*)\/$
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/dO4hY6/1

And if you want to match the id after `sale` you can use following regex:

```
sale\/([^/]*)\/
```

Comment: Why is everybody using `/` as delimiters? Why not use `~` - your regex would become much more beautiful: `~/([^/]*)/$~` or `~sale/([^/]*)/~`, respectively.

Comment: @Jan Actually I didn't used any delimiter but I'm agree with you `~` is much beautiful. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\/sale\/)[^\/]+\//
```

Replace with `\1` or `$1`.

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/bP4fG8/1)

---

If your language supports lookbehinds, you could:

```
/(?<=\/sale\/)[^\/]+\//
```

Replace with empty string.

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/bP4fG8/2)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is, if all of your IDs are in the exact same format (in this case, 10 digits, a hyphen, then 5 alphanumeric characters), you can search for the pattern directly using something like this `(\d{10}-\w{5})`